# How to identify the object that consumes the most bandwidth in an AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What is the best way to identify the object that consumes the most bandwidth in a S3 bucket with thousands of other objects ?

Answer (score 0):

By "bandwidth" I will assume that you mean the bandwidth consumed by delivering files from S3 to some place on the Internet (as when you use S3 to serve static assets).

To track this, you'll need to enable [S3 access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html), which creates logfiles *in a different bucket* that show all of the operations against your primary bucket (or a path in it).

Here are two examples of logged GET operations. The first is from anonymous Internet access using a public S3 URL, while the second uses the AWS CLI to download the file. I've redacted or modified any identifying fields, but you should be able to figure out the format from what remains.

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx com-example-mybucket [04/Feb/2020:15:50:00 +0000] 3.4.5.6 - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX REST.GET.OBJECT index.html "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 - 90 90 9 8 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx - ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 - com-example-mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com TLSv1.2
```

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx com-example-mybucket [05/Feb/2020:14:51:44 +0000] 3.4.5.6 arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/me XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX REST.GET.OBJECT index.html "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 - 90 90 29 29 "-" "aws-cli/1.17.7 Python/3.6.9 Linux/4.15.0-76-generic botocore/1.14.7" - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SigV4 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 AuthHeader com-example-mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com TLSv1.2
```

So, to get what you want:

1. Enable logging
2. Wait for a representative amount of data to be logged. At least 24 hours unless you're a high-volume website (and note that it can take up to an hour for log records to appear).
3. Extract all the lines that contain `REST.GET.OBJECT`
4. From these, extract the filename and the  number of bytes (in this case, the file is 90 bytes).
5. For each file, multiply the number of bytes by the number of times that it appears in a given period.

*Beware:* because every access is logged, the logfiles can grow quite large, quite fast, and you will pay for storage charges. You should create a life-cycle rule on the destination bucket to delete old logs.

*Update:* you could also use Athena to query this data. [Here's an AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/analyze-logs-athena/) that describes the process.

Comment: Note that I dont know the filename. I'm trying to identify what is the most downloaded filename.

Comment: @boblapointe - that's step #4: "extract the filename and the number of bytes".